# When using CURL with https. The code only work on localhost, do not work on live website. I can not find out why?

Tags: php, curl, https, file-get-contents, cloudflare

This is the php code that I am using.
I tested this code on localhost (xampp) and everything ok. but when I upload this code to my host (1and1 hosting) This code will not work. Please help me to find out why?
Thank you very much!

```
$url = "https://www.packagetrackr.com/track/1ZX799390355046642";
$page = get_web_page($url);
echo $page;

function get_web_page($url)
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // Disabled SSL Cert checks
        CURLOPT_REFERER        => $url      // referent
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Is curl available? is ssl available? Try a file with `<?php phpinfo();` to find out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My hosting have curl but do not have ssl!

Answer (score 0):

you can try turn on **allow_url_fopen** in your php.ini file

or

**php_value allow_url_fopen On** in .htaccess